# Regex to match 2 level deep URL and not 1 or 3 level deep (Data Studio)

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to write RegEx which will let me filter on URLs beginning with /types/ that contain only these 2 slashes. For example, /types/lung-cancer should be captured but /types/lung-cancer/treatments should not be captured.

I found RegEx which works in Google Analytics but it does not work in Looker Studio. I replaced the \ delimiter with / as needed in Looker Studio and it still doesn't work.

Here is what I have:
REGEXP_CONTAINS(Page path without query string,'^//types//([^//]+)//$')

I have tried a variety of RegEx

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
REGEXP_MATCH(URL_,"^/types/[^/]*")
```

[image]